# Knitting to PDF has different output size using Mac and Windows

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown, knitr

I try to knit Rmd to PDF using Windows and result in very small output of several figures (created using plotly). But when my friend knit **the same code** using her Mac, she can get normal output size and layout.
I have tried all setting to make the size normal (ie out.width fig.with) but no luck.
Why does the same code result in different PDF output in windows and mac?
PDF result using Windows:

[image]

PDF result using Mac:

[image]

Comment: Do you use the exact same version of kitr, plotly etc on both systems?

Comment: Yes. The different is just our operating system. I already update all to the newest version. This problem also happen to my other friend who also uses windows. Our problem is when knitting to PDF for interactive plots i.e. Plotly, Timevis, Leaflet. We got small size plot like the sample picture I attached before.